# SocketAsyncEventArgs vs TcpListener/TcpClient

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener, socketasynceventargs

Consider this example scenario:

Client
1. One data as message
2. send to server 10000 times the same one data message
3. at one time only connect to one server

Server
1. receive message from 1000 client concurrently(if possible. if not, as much as possible)
2. discard the received message in memory(no need to write to file)

This scenario is easily implemented with TcpListener/TcpClient. However, i need to stress the machines.

Which one should i use; SocketAsyncEventArgs or TcpListener/TcpClient? Why? Does this scenario benefits SocketAsyncEventArgs reusable objects?